# exclude target redirection file from being processed in for loop

Tags: shell, io-redirection, wildcards

This will cause `LIST` to grow very large (even a couple of GB in a short time etc):

```
$ for i in *; do echo $i; cut -d '   ' -f1 $i ; done > LIST
```

For example, after 10 seconds:

```
$ wc -l LIST
132654955 LIST
$ ls -hl LIST
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 2.3G Jan 22 21:35 LIST
```

I think that the reason is that `LIST` is added to the list of files
that should be processed and `cut` never finishes processing it. I
found 3 solutions for this problem:

- exclude `LIST` from being processed:

  ```
  for i in !(LIST); do echo $i; cut -d '     ' -f1 $i ; done > LIST
  ```
- use another directory for `LIST`:

  ```
  for i in *; do echo $i; cut -d '     ' -f1 $i ; done > /tmp/LIST
  ```
- expand `*` before running the loop with `C-x *` or whatever `$ bind
  -p | grep glob-expand-word` shows

Is my reasoning correct and which way is the best here?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

Among your proposed solutions, i prefer the first two specially the second one as it seems cleaner to write to a file located in another directory.

Here is another option using `GLOBIGNORE` variable (Given your shell supports this):

```
GLOBIGNORE=LIST  ## "LIST" file will be ignored while globbing
for i in *; do echo "$i"; cut -d '   ' -f1 "$i"; done >LIST
```

Comment: nice, I have never heard about `GLOBIGNORE`, thx

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing activity on every file in a folder and putting the output file in the same folder, is not a wise approach in my opinion. My `>` output redirections always end up in `/tmp`, unless I know there is not enough space for my output there. Then I look for a more suitable filesystem for it. But never place them in the same directory as I am processing the input files from.

Comment: "If you are performing activity on every file in a folder and putting the output file in the same folder, is not a wise approach in my opinion" - rather a broad brush

Comment: Less testing against unwanted effects if I do it this way. Simple is better. Always. Let it be a broad brush. Unless there is a need for complex code, say for performance purposes, because it is going to run multiple times every minute or every few seconds, it is a different story. But for a sysadmin script which will run a handful times at best, putting effort into testing conditions that one might avoid with simple precautions, like placing the log file outside, will always be _my_ preference